# Form of ideal that contains non maximal ideal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $A$ be a commutative ring with unity, and let $I$ be a non-maximal ideal of $A$. Then there exists an ideal $J$ such that $I\subsetneqq J\subsetneqq A$.

Is there a general way of finding $J$?

For example, is $J$ of the form $\{ab+i:b\in A,i\in I\}$ and $a\in A$ is fixed?

Comment: To prove the existence of maximal ideal, you need choice ( zorn's lemma, an equivalent version of AC).

Comment: @LostinSpace Sorry?

Comment: It's a good question.

Comment: Without more information, there's no general way to actually _find_ such an ideal $J$, although the _existence_ of such an ideal $J$ can be proved via Zorn's Lemma (equivalent to the Axiom of Choice).

Comment: @quasi: you absolutely do not need Zorn's lemma here. The existence of such a $J$ follows immediately by definition from the condition that $I$ is non-maximal.

Comment: @Rishi I know $J$ need not be unique. That doesn't imply there is one $J$ that is not of the given form.

Comment: True, if you assume $I$ is non-maxinal, then you know such an ideal $J$ exists, but that info alone does not give a way to actually _find_ such an ideal $J$.

Comment: @quasi: yes, but neither does Zorn's lemma. We are simply given that there is a set, namely the set of proper ideals properly containing $I$, and it is non-empty. Zorn's lemma is not required to select an element from a single non-empty set.

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan: Agreed, given that $I$ is non-maximal, Zorn's lemma isn't needed to assert the existence of such an ideal $J$ (unless you want $J$ to be maximal), but I'm fairly sure that what the OP is hoping for is a general method for actually finding such an ideal $J$ (other than just arguing that since at least one such an ideal $J$ exists, choose one and call it $J$).

Comment: @quasi Yes, that's exactly what I'm hoping for. Any idea?

Comment: @Pedro García: Without more information, there's nothing that really qualifies as a general method. If you have some specific instances in mind, pick one and ask it as a new question (but make sure to include some work, showing your attempt).